# ¿Cómo recorro un arreglo dentro de una función anónima con parámetro global?

Tags: java, java-swing, funciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < numElementos; i++){
            palillos[i] = new JLabel() {
            /**
            * Para rotar el palillo.
            * @param grafico 
            */
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics grafico) {
            Graphics2D graficoNuevo = (Graphics2D) grafico;
            graficoNuevo.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );
            AffineTransform at = graficoNuevo.getTransform();
            Shape figura = graficoNuevo.getClip();
            double X = getWidth() / 2.0;
            double Y = getHeight() / 2.0;
            /**
            *
            * Aquí es donde tengo el problema, no puedo me salen los valores 
            * si coloco la i que itera el arreglo.
            */
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(gradosInclinacionPalillos[i]), X, Y);
            /**
            * Intento que con cada JLabel creado se tenga una rotación de la 
            * imagen que contiene el JLabel diferente.
            */
            graficoNuevo.setTransform(at);
            graficoNuevo.setClip(figura);
            super.paintComponent(grafico);
        }
    };
   panel.add(palillos[i]).setBounds(coordenadasPalillos[i][0], coordenadasPalillos[i][1], 18, 65);
}
```

Quiero acceder a los valores del vector para poder asignarle la rotación que deseo a ese elemento, hice el vector público para poder acceder los valores sin problemas, pero esto no genera problemas porque este vector es una estructura prácticamente estática, ya tiene todos sus valores asignados y su tamaño no difiere del que tiene al comenzar.

Entonces, imagino que el problema de la variable con la que itero, `i` , es que cambia su valor con el tiempo, y eso da problemas con la función anónima del JLabel.

Por favor, una ayuda para poder iterar ese vector y cambiar esa rotación.

Comment: Podrás subir la clase completa?, quiero ver donde creas palillos[]; desde donde queres acceder?, desde esa clase o de otra?.

Comment: Desde esta misma clase, el arreglo de palillos está declarado en la misma clase.

Answer (score 0):

Cree una clase que extiende de JLabel con un constructor que recibe como parámetro la inclinación y sobreescribí el método paintComponent:

```
public class MyJLabel extends JLabel {
    private final double inclinacion;
    public MyJLabel(double inclinacion) {
        super();
        this.inclinacion = inclinacion;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grafico) {
        Graphics2D graficoNuevo = (Graphics2D) grafico;
        graficoNuevo.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
        );
        AffineTransform at = graficoNuevo.getTransform();
        Shape figura = graficoNuevo.getClip();
        double X = getWidth() / 2.0;
        double Y = getHeight() / 2.0;

        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(inclinacion), X, Y);
        graficoNuevo.setTransform(at);
        graficoNuevo.setClip(figura);
        super.paintComponent(grafico);
    }
}
```